# Creating your personal colors in Xcode for iOS 5

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3

How can you make custom colors in Xcode 4.3.2 for iOS5?

I have a few different colors that I would like to make.

- http://www.colorhexa.com/5893bd
- http://www.colorhexa.com/1a78be

Answer (score 2):

http://www.colorhexa.com/5893bd
"In a RGB color space, hex #5893bd is composed of **34.5%red**, **57.6% green** and **74.1%blue**."

Convert the percentage of the colors to decimals and enter the code in this function.

```
colorWithRed: 0.345 green: 0.576 blue
```

Comment: There is a missing 0.741 following the blue in this example.